# Time derivative for vectors and matrixes on the real field

Tags: isabelle

I'm looking for the lemmas of the time derivative of vectors with finite dimension on the real numbers (finite-dimensional real vector spaces like `ℝ^n`) and on matrixes also with `ℝ^nxn`. I found the jacobian derivative of matrixes `Cartesian_Euclidean_Space`. Could anyone guide me to the theory name or how to implement the time derivative with vectors and matrixes?

Comment: I've never used this myself really, but I think it should just be `has_vector_derivative` and `vector_derivative` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I found these definitions but I'm not sure if they are for vectors on `ℝ^n` dimension because the type defined is not as any dimensional vector.

Comment: `has_vector_derivative` has the type `(real ⇒ 'a::real_normed_vector) ⇒ 'a ⇒ real filter ⇒ bool`. Since `real ^ n` has a type class instance for `real_normed_vector`, you can use `has_vector_derivative` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've taken a brief look at the theory we have in Isabelle and this is what I came up with:

- The concept you are looking for is called a *vector derivative* in Isabelle.
- The operation itself is called `vector_derivative` and is defined on any real normed vector space.
- In practice, you almost never use `vector_derivative` though, but you instead use `has_vector_derivative`

For instance, you can prove the following:

```
lemma
  "((λt. (t, t^2)) has_vector_derivative (1, 2*t)) (at t)"
  by (auto intro!: derivative_eq_intros 
           simp: has_field_derivative_iff_has_vector_derivative [symmetric])
```

Here, I show that the curve t ↦ (t, t²) has the derivative (1, 2t). Note that for convenience, I used `real × real` instead of `real ^ 2` here, the reason being that the former is more convenient for demonstration. Depending on what you want to do exactly, working with `real × real × real` instead of `real ^ 3` may also be more convenient for you.

Also note the related concept of a `field_derivative`. This is the ‘normal’ derivative on a normed field, (e.g. the real or complex numbers). In the above proof, the automation first reduces the goal to showing what the *vector derivatives* of `t` and `t ^ 2` are, and the last rule in the proof takes care of reducing that to showing what the *field derivatives* are (since these are now real functions), and that can be done automatically.

Comment: That what I expected but I didn't sure. That was very clear Manuel, thanks for your effort to find out and clarify things. I will work on and see how is going. Cheers